# Help in writing an sql query

Tags: sql

I am trying to write a query that would fetch the number of player in a sports team for every country in the table:

I have a table with the following fields

```
country | sports_team | player_name
```

What I want to display is a reulst similar to this

```
country | sports_team | number_of_players
```

i.e. I would like to loop through all the countries, and for every change in sports_team, I would like to record the nummber of players that are in the team.

Sample table:

```
country | sports_team | player_name
c1      |  teamA      |  name1
c1      |  teamA      |  name2
c1      |  teamB      |  name3
c2      |  teamC      |  name4
c2      |  teamC      |  name5
```

Sample results

```
country | sports_team | number_of_players
c1      | teamA       | 2
c1      | teamB       | 1
c2      | teamC       | 2
```

I am new to writing sql queries and I have no idea how to procede, any help will be appreciated!

Comment: try reading just a small amount on SELECT statements.  this should be on about page 2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT country, sports_team, COUNT(*) AS number_of_players
FROM yourtable
GROUP BY country, sports_team
ORDER BY country, sports_team;
```

[*Aggregate*](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-functions.html) queries like `COUNT` are the key for this sort of data processing.

Answer (score 3):

Use [GROUP BY](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp):

```
SELECT country, sports_team, COUNT(*)
FROM whatever_your_table_is    
GROUP BY country, sports_team
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select 
  country,
  sports_team,
  count(*) number_of_players
from table
group by country, sports_team
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to select the country and team and group by those columns to display the count. This will work for you:

```
SELECT 
  Country, Sports_Team, COUNT(player_name) AS number_of_players
FROM 
  YourTable
GROUP BY 
  Country, Sports_Team
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select country, sports_team, count(*) from <your table> group by country, sports_team
```

Answer (score 1):

No need to loop, just aggregate.

```
SELECT country, sports_team, COUNT(*)
FROM myTable
GROUP BY country, sports_team
```

The magic is in the `COUNT(*)` and the `GROUP BY` clause