# SQL get count per repeated value in field

Tags: mysql, sql, count, sum

I have a table similar to the following. (The addresses are actually IP addresses, but I'm keeping them short for simplicity.)

```
| Cust ID | Address |
| ------- | --------|
|    1    | 111     |
|    1    | 222     |
|    1    | 222     |
|    1    | 222     |
|    1    | 333     | 
|    2    | 444     | 
|    2    | 444     | 
|    2    | 444     |
|    2    | 444     |
|    3    | 555     |
```

I would like to get the count of the different addresses for each customer, sorted by the counts:

```
| Cust ID | Address | Count |
| ------- | --------|-------|
|    2    | 444     |   4   |
|    1    | 222     |   3   |
|    1    | 111     |   1   |
|    1    | 333     |   1   |
|    3    | 555     |   1   |
```

So, per above, customer 2 used the address 444 four times; customer 1 used the address 222 three times, 111 one time, and 333 one time; etc.

FWIW, I'm using mysql.

Thanks!

Comment: It's not a sum of count, but rather, just a count().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT   CustID, Address, COUNT(*)
FROM     Cust
GROUP BY CustID, Address
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC;
```

A good rule of thumb when using GROUP BY is to pass it all selected columns not used by COUNT.

Comment: *Try this* is not considered an answer here. If you know it works, explain how and why it works. If you're not sure, then don't post an answer.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6654348/16373651

Answer (score 1):

To aggregate the frequency of addresses among the different customer IDs, a GROUP BY clause is used in conjunction with a COUNT clause to determine the frequency of addresses for each customer ID.

```
SELECT Cust ID, Address, COUNT(*) FROM TABLE GROUP BY Cust ID, Address ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC;
```

Please note that for the GROUP BY clause, both Cust ID and Address are being grouped. COUNT(*) is being used to count all entries that appear within each group.

As another example, if one only wished to determine the frequency of addresses while disregarding which customer ID they belong to - one would only group by Address:

```
SELECT Address, COUNT(*) FROM TABLE GROUP BY Address ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC;
```

However, grouping by multiple columns (as in the first case) narrows down the results to ensure that aggregates across both of the relevant columns are considered.

Answer (score 0):

select CustId,
Address,
count(Address) as Count

from Cust

Group by CustId, Address;